# Passing register name in mapping to an ex command

Tags: vim

Suppose I want to create a map in vim that will call an ex command as part of its work. And suppose that the ex command takes a register name as input.

Here is a toy example:

```
nmap <leader>p :put x
```

The problem there is that the 'x' register will always be used.
But when typing, I want to be able to write:

```
"a<leader>p
```

To use the 'a' register, or:

```
"b<leader>p
```

to use the 'b' register.

Is there a way that I can pass the 'current normal-mode register' along to the 'ex' command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out.

The trick is to use `<expr>` in the mapping.

So, for my example, the answer is:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>p ':put ' . v:register . '<CR>'
```

Check `:h map-expression` and `:h v:register` for more info.

Comment: [Use `nnoremap`.](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html)